# Can't get val() from shopify input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

Shopify auto generates a form at checkout by way of `{{ content_for_order_summary }}` in which there is a gift card input:

```
<input placeholder=“Gift card or discount code” class=“field__input” data- 
discount-field=“true” data-trekkie-id=“reduction_code_field” 
autocomplete=“off” aria-required=“true” size=“30” type=“text” 
name=“checkout[reduction_code]” id=“checkout_reduction_code”>
```

I am trying to get the value of this input with:
`$(‘#checkout_reduction_code’).val();`

This doesn't work though. I can inject a value then retrieve it just fine using the same selector so I know it's properly selected.

My question is exactly this:
Does anyone know why / had experience with this before? How on earth can i get the value of the input? My co-worker and i have tried almost everything.

Here's the working codepen with the whole form.
[codepen](https://codepen.io/archae0pteryx-the-bold/pen/aPYZWd)

Comment: IDs are unique so your selector is pretty redundant. You can just use `#checkout_reduction_code`. Also If it is in a click handler it doesnt need to be in document ready. And you dont need the click handler to be in a document ready either if you just put your javascript at the end of your page.

Comment: I agree with @Marie here, just use the ID, it MUST be unique and it is the fastest re `$('#checkout_reduction_code').val();` - if it is NOT unique, that is an error that must be corrected.  Please add more code and markup - perhaps there is an error in that somewhere...?

Comment: Yeah...We're just at a total loss and were trying everything imaginable. The id is in fact unique @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: Step 1 to debugging jquery is to make sure the selector actually returns something. jQuery wont error if you call a method on a selector with no results. Open the console and run `$('#checkout_reduction_code').length`. If it is zero something is amis

Comment: maybe the problem *is* `document.ready()` ... is the element rendered(and has a value) "at document.ready"? ...or maybe later (dynamically loaded) ... (u can track this with "browser dev tools" ~ "network profiling")

Comment: We took that out just now. We've been just trying to debug in the console at this point. The strange thing is that we are able to inject a val then retrieve it just fine.

Comment: @archae0pteryx You can put a functional example in your question using the snippet insert or make an example at jsfiddle or codepen. We will be able to help you much more easily if we can see a bare functional example of the issue you are having.

Comment: The problem is that it will work just fine in codepen. It has to be something specific to the way shopify is dynamically generating the field. That's my best guess.

Comment: You say "Will work." did you actually try? Also check to make sure you are actually using jQuery and not some other `$` library. Check `$.fn.jquery` in the console. Either way seeing more code gives us more to go on so a working example would still help

Comment: @archae0pteryx I guess you might have already checked it out but still does this help? https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/value-of-the-custom-input-field-what-s-the-liquid-syntax-199205

Comment: @marie it is jQuery. Yup. I tried in codepen and works as expected.

Comment: Can you show us your pen so we can see what you are trying? Somebody familiar with shopify might recognize what the issues is based on your implementation.

Comment: @marie i just added the link to codepen

Comment: Try tossing `console.log($('button.field__input-btn').length > 0)` before the click bind.  Make sure the selector for the button actually finds the button

Comment: @marie yup it's there and found.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go with a guess here, well really just a pair of guesses.

1. First, attach the click event handler to the parent of the element. Works for dynamically created elements inside the parent wrapper better.
2. More importantly, **prevent the submit** which is the default type for a button however, you have also specifically set it to `type="submit"` - so it probably does that and gets in the way of your click handler.
3. Does it have value? force some in there

```js
// just for the test, force content in there
$("#checkout_reduction_code").val("test me");
$('.order-summary__section').on("click", ".field__input-btn", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent the default submit
  console.log("Clicked");
  console.log($("#checkout_reduction_code").length);
  const cardCode = $("#checkout_reduction_code").val();
  console.log(cardCode.length, ":" + cardCode + ":");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="order-summary__section order-summary__section--discount" data-reduction-form="update">
  <h3 class="visually-hidden">Gift card or discount code</h3>
  <form class="edit_checkout animate-floating-labels" action="/8572698682/checkouts/ec0c9981ed8878d2c547acd14bc66825" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="uy4G7N445kuNoDYYrwNwZqANThycax+sD1ZgsPNdJEgpu7VFCRlc8EZtdGMSFfxNukx/VjJZK/9rapjY7nM8mg==">
    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="payment_method">
  </form>

  <form class="edit_checkout animate-floating-labels" action="/8572698682/checkouts/ec0c9981ed8878d2c547acd14bc66825" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" _lpchecked="1"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="CIbBD3nktheTkrboQ8CE6WBzA4KDgv5iJFC6wMP+x3iaE3KmrsUMrFhf9JP+1gjCejIyyC2wyjFAbEKo3tDfqg==">
    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="payment_method">
    <div class="fieldset">
      <div class="field field--show-floating-label">

        <div class="field__input-btn-wrapper">
          <div class="field__input-wrapper"><label class="field__label field__label--visible" for="checkout_reduction_code">Gift card or discount code</label>
            <input placeholder="Gift card or discount code" class="field__input" data-discount-field="true" data-trekkie-id="reduction_code_field" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" size="30" type="text" name="checkout[reduction_code]" id="checkout_reduction_code">
          </div>

          <button name="button" type="submit" class="field__input-btn btn" data-trekkie-id="apply_discount_button" aria-busy="false">
              <span class="btn__content visually-hidden-on-mobile" aria-hidden="true">
                Apply
              </span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">
                Apply Discount Code
              </span>
              <svg class="icon-svg icon-svg--size-16 btn__icon shown-on-mobile" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"> <use xlink:href="#arrow"></use> </svg>
              <svg class="icon-svg icon-svg--size-18 btn__spinner icon-svg--spinner-button" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"> <use xlink:href="#spinner-button"></use> </svg>
</button> </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately this still does not work. We've decided to create a modal in which the user puts the number in first (so we can grab it and do work) then we inject it back into the original form... This is decidedly noodle-ish but the best we can come up with...